# How many pairwise non-isomorphic simple graphs are there of 60 points and 1768 edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> How many pairwise non-isomorphic simple graphs are there of 60 points and 1768 edges?

I'm having some trouble trying to figure this one out. Is there a general solution to solve this? Previous posts said to draw graphs, but I feel that it's pretty difficult to do realistically given the number of points and edges.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** How many edges total are possible in a simple graph with 60 points?

**Hint 2:** Consider the [graph complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph).  How many edges would any graph complement of a graph with 60 vertices and 1768 edges have?

> **Hint 3:** How many graphs on 60 vertices exist with only two edges?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The complete graph on $60$ vertices has
$${60\choose 2}=1770$$
edges. How many ways can you remove 2 edges and be left with non-isomorphic graphs?